# Better shell solution when blank lines may be piped to wc

Tags: shell-script, shell, newlines

I have code that does something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
CONTENTS=$(cat "somefile")
RELEVANT_LINES=$(echo "$CONTENTS" | grep -E "SEARCHEXPR")
COUNT=$(echo "$RELEVANT_LINES" | wc -l)
```

I hit an annoyance that this code didn't output the same if there weren't any matches, compared to the correct output given by replacing the third line with :

```
COUNT=$(echo "$CONTENTS" | grep -E "SEARCHEXPR" | wc -l)
```

I eventually traced to the fact that when there weren't any matches, RELEVANT_LINES was being set to the empty string, and echo was outputting a one line empty string + \n for a line count of 1.

I tried using printf and echo -n in the 3rd line, but couldn't find the elegant workaround and ended up using `COUNT=$(echo "$RELEVANT_LINES" | grep '0' | wc -l)` (all lines contain a zero) to avoid having to regex filter the entire source file twice.

That can't be right, but I can't figure the correct fix.

I didn't drop to scripting with `-eq ''` because I wasn't sure it would be as robust and I prefer piping directly to `wc` for pure neatness.

Any hints how to get file content in a variable, to neatly distinguish zero vs one line after being filtered by grep? :)

Comment: Can't the whole thing be replaced by `COUNT=$(grep -Ec "SEARCHEXPR" somefile)` ?

Answer (score 4):

Using `CONTENTS` to hold the file just to `echo` it again is a bit redundant, you could just

```
lines=$(cat "somefile" | grep -E "SEARCHEXPR")
```

or rather

```
lines=$(grep -E "SEARCHEXPR" "somefile")
```

If you just want the count of matching lines, use `grep -c`

```
count=$(grep -c -E "SEARCHEXPR" "somefile")
```

The immediate issue you see is caused by the fact that `echo` outputs the newline always. In the case where you get at least one line from the command substitutions, this actually helps, since command substitutions *remove trailing newlines*. It also works with tailing empty lines, try this to see: `x=$(echo foo; echo; echo); echo "$x"`.

If you want to process the lines in the shell script in some other way, in addition to counting, then storing the text in a variable might not be best. You could try

```
for line in $lines ; do 
    something with "$line"
done
```

But that has the usual issues with unquoted variables, i.e. filename globbing and word splitting on whitespace. One line containing "foo bar doo", would be seen as three, since by default, the spaces split too.

You might want to use a `while read` loop instead, but for that, a shell that supports process substitution might be good to have. See [BashFAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and [variable doesn't change after find & while](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274227/variable-doesnt-change-after-find-while) and [in bash, read after a pipe is not setting values](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143958/in-bash-read-after-a-pipe-is-not-setting-values) .